# How to remove extra space between controls in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I currently have this.

http://jsfiddle.net/ef7vh/1/

```
<div>
   <button>Button1</button>
   <span style="border: solid 1px black; padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px">My Text</span>
   <button>Button2</button>
</div>
```

How do you remove the right spacing on button1 and left spacing on button 2 so they are touching the middle span?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    button {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

span {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Would be one (of many) solution(s).

Answer (score 1):

The reason, there's a space between button and span, is a button has set property of display as inline-block. Inline-block elements are having margins added automatically. You have to remove margins, for example by adding float or setting button as inline element.

Answer (score 1):

You have whitespace between inputs.

Look at [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ef7vh/7/)